# Qualified-ids, are they lvalues or prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, lvalue, qualified-name

I was trying to validate this statement (my emphasis) in paragraph §5.1.1/8 (page 87) of the C++11 Standard

> A nested-name-specifier that denotes a class, optionally followed by
>   the keyword template (14.2), and then followed by the name of a member
>   of either that class (9.2) or one of its base classes (Clause 10), is
>   a qualified-id; 3.4.3.1 describes name lookup for class members that
>   appear in qualified-ids. The result is the member. The type of the
>   result is the type of the member. **The result is an lvalue if the
>   member is a static member function or a data member and a prvalue
>   otherwise**.

with the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N {
    class A {
    public:
        int i;
        void f();
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << &N::A::f << '\n';
    std::cout << &N::A::i << '\n';
}
```

`clang` and `gcc` compile this code and `VS2013` requires the definition of the member function `f`.

All three of them print

```
1
1
```

but I have no idea where these numbers come from.

[live example](http://rextester.com/WKAN91227)

According to the paragraph highlighted above the expressions `N::A::f` is a prvalue, as `f` is not a static member function. Nonetheless, I was able to take its address in the code.

At the same time, in §5.3.1/3 one reads (emphasis mine):

> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The
>   operand shall be an lvalue **or** a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a
>   *qualified-id* naming a non-static member m of some class C with type T,
>   the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a
>   prvalue designating C::m.

which gives the impression that neither `N::A::f` nor `N::A::i` are lvalues, as they are *qualified-id*s.

Comment: `1` is the pointer-to-member converted to `bool`.

Comment: *qualified-ids* can be either. In `class C { static int x; };`, `C::x` is obviously an lvalue. And the or in 5.3.1/3 isn't exclusive.

Comment: There are qualified-ids which are certainly prvalues: `struct foo { enum bar { name = 0 }; };` with those definitions, `foo::name` is a prvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I have no idea where these numbers come from.

Pointer-to-members aren't pointers. No `operator<<` can output their original value, the best *and only* match is the one that outputs `bool` values. Thus they are converted to `bool` (which obviously yields `true`) and the output is `1`. Try to insert `std::boolalpha` and check the output again.

> Nonetheless, I was able to take its address in the code.

How is that a surprise to you? You quoted the part that allows and explains this exact construct. It clearly states that taking the adress of a qualified-id that names a non-static member designates that member.

*qualified-id*s are not only lvalues or rvalues. It completely depends on context. If they designate non-static members from outside that members class or any subclass of it, they have to be prvalues as they don't designate any specific object but rather a value (or information, in other words -- the type and an offset).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `bool`?

Comment: @Aneri Why not? There is a conversion to `bool`, there is no conversion to any other type for which any `operator<<` is defined.

Comment: "Actually, all three compilers require a definition of `f`." -- Both clang and gcc do not diagnose the lack of a definition when optimisations are enabled.

Comment: @hvd Yes, with optimizations enabled. Is that irrelevant? Anyway, removed that part, as it really doesn't matter

Comment: @Loopunroller It explains why you might get an error message for it even though the OP didn't, and I felt that was worth clearing up.

Comment: @hvd Ah, okay. I didn't compile with optimizations on because of this  situation.

Comment: _qualified-ids are not only lvalues or rvalues. It completely depends on context. If they designate non-static members from outside that members class or any subclass of it, they have to be prvalues_ This is still not the case, unfortunately :(